# How do you retrieve the value of a dynamic key name from the results of a register command in ansible

Tags: ansible, dynamic-variables

I am looking to retrieve the value of a key (which will have a different key name each time) from a third-party module output.

A simple replication of what I am trying to achieve is as follows:
I have a variable -

```
secure_name: "ALIAS_HTTPD_HOSTNAME1'
```

I then run the task:

```
- name: retrieve param name
  shell:
    cmd: "echo {{ secure_name }} | cut -'_' -f2-"
  register secure_param_name
```

I have a third module which takes the above **{{ secure_param_name.stdout|upper }}** as a parameter to retrieve the name value pair from a third party software for holding secure key pairs.

The output of the third party module is stored in a register var called: **secure_results**

The output of the third party module call is:

```
{
    "changed": false,
    "_ansible_no_log: false,
    "HTTPD_HOSTNAME1": "SERVERNAME1"
}
```

if i issue:

```
-debug: msg="{{ secure_results.HTTPD_HOSTNAME1 }}"
```

i get the required output SERVERNAME1

I don't however want to have to hardcode every param I wish to retrieve.  I wish to be able to use the value of secure_param_name.stdout to make up the variable_name

I have tried:

```
-debug: msg="{{'secure_results.'+secure_param_name.stdout }}
```

but this only returns: secure_results.HTTPD_HOSTNAME1

How do I resolve the above dynamic variable name?
using 2 sets of {{ {{ }} }} doesn't work.

I have also tried:

```
- debug: msg="{{ vars['secure_results.' ~ secure_param_name.stdout] }}"
```

this errors with 'dict object' has no attibute u'secure_results.HTTPD_HOSTNAME1'

I am a little confused as to why its not finding the dictionary object 'secure_results.HTTPD_HOSTNAME1' when placing that same string in {{ }} retrieves the value as shown in the first debug above.

Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I think I have this working now by using the following:

```
- debug: msg="{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['secure_results'][secure_param_name.stdout] }}"
```

would that be the best way to do this?